# How to create a facebook page with an iframe tab that points to a dynamic URL?

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

There are two key parts to my question :

1. How to create a facebook page which points to a dynamic path.
2. How to generate this page programmatically.

The various how-to's that I have found, such as this one 
http://www.lightcms.com/how-to-set-up-custom-facebook-page-tabs-with-content-your-clients-can-control 
do answer this question without addressing those specific requirements.

Essentially I want to have users who are on my main website, press a button, that generates a facebook tab for them that they can add to their own Facebook page. The tab contents are different for each user because the URL will depend on their use id, hence the dynamic requirement. I don't expect most of these users to have the technical know how to create a facebook app and attach it as a tab to their page either, hence the need to simplify the process.

How can this be done?

I am agnostic to the language used, but would prefer either a nodejs or java based solution, where possible.

Comment: You don't need a dynamic url. Just let them add your app. In the signed_request that you get in the POST request the page id will be. So you can change stuff depending on what the page id is.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Page ID in your App, so the content can be different for every Page.

If you want to make it different for every User, you could use the app_data parameter:

https://www.facebook.com/[vanity-url]/app_xxxxxx?app_data=[user-id]

app_data is available in the signed_request POST parameter when you add it to the URL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games

You would have to create a Canvas App (or external Website) where the User would authorize your App > that way you can get his User ID, you store it in your database and in your code of the Page App you compare the app_data value with the data in your database. I hope this does not sound too complicated, it really isn´t if you check out how to use signed_request and app_data.

You can also generate a unique key for the app_data parameter, of course. After authorization of the User, you just create a key with php (see Google for plenty of resources about how to create unique keys) and you store that one in your database instead of the User ID.

Comment: luschn, could you point me to the documentation for how to use the `app_data` parameter, and how to generate unique keys for it please? How would this work on my end - how would I enable the user to install the app as a tab on their page?

Comment: app_data is in the signed_request parameter, i will edit my answer with a link to the facebook docs.